# Variable not defined Outlook to Excel importing

Tags: vba

I am extremely new to VBA, I am trying to get files from a specific folder and sender and am using this code I found on YT, I added the sender section but I keep getting variable not defined:

```
Option Explicit

Sub getDataFromOutlookChoiceFolder()
Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Long

Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application
Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.PickFolder

If Folder.Items.Count = 0 Then
MsgBox "No emails. Exiting procedure!"
Exit Sub
End If

i = 1

Dim rngName As Name
Sheet1.Cells.Clear
For Each rngName In ActiveWorkbook.Names
rngName.Delete
Next

Range("A1").Name = "email_Subject"
Range("A1") = "EmailSubject"
Range("B1").Name = "email_Date"
Range("B1") = "Email Date"
Range("C1").Name = "email_Sender"
Range("email_Sender")**.Value = InputBox("Enter Sender Addresss")**
Range("D1").Name = "email_Body"
Range("D1") = "Email Body"
Range("E1").Name = "email_Receipt_Date"
Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value = InputBox("Enter Receipt Date like 20-mar-2020")

For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("email_Receipt_Date").Value **And OutlookMail.Sender = Range(“email_Sender”)** Then
Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range("email_Subject").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range("email_Date").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range("email_Sender").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Body
Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).Columns.AutoFit
Range("email_Body").Offset(i, 0).VerticalAlignment = xlTop

i = i + 1
End If
Next OutlookMail

Set Folder = Nothing
Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Highlighted is my changes. It works fine when just trying to select from a specific inbox

Comment: What line is raising the error?

Answer (score 0):

```
...And OutlookMail.Sender = Range(“email_Sender”)
```

You have "smart quotes" in there. VBA does not see those as actual quotes, but just another character, so it's sort of like writing

```
...And OutlookMail.Sender = Range(Xemail_SenderX)
```

You have not declared any variable named (eg) `Xemail_SenderX`, which is why you get the complaint about undeclared variable.